# What's the relationship between partitions and parallelism in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read data by spark-shell:

```
spark.read.json("s3://some").rdd.partitions.length
```

It returns 43.

Then I set a parameter: `--conf spark.default.parallelism=3000`, execute above code, it returns 1150.

Why not 3000? why not return the num I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark.default.parallelism is the **largest number** of partitions in a parent RDD after applying distributed shuffle operations like reduceByKey and join ( **Only on RDD**, this configuration **does not take effects on DataFrame**).

In the exemple you provided, you set the max partition number so it is a okay to have a result < spark.default.parallelism.

PS: The default number of partition can be set depending on the available memory across the nodes. For exemple: Number of partitions = available Memory in MB/256 MB As a result you'll have 256MB per partition.